# Inequality on MGF implies inequality on tails?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $\mathbb{E}(X-a)_+ \leq \mathbb{E}(Y-a)_+, \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$ then we have $$\forall t\geq 0, \; \mathbf{P}[Y\geq t] \leq \kappa e^{-bt} ⟹ \forall t\geq 0, \;\mathbf{P}[X\geq t] \leq \kappa e^{1-bt}.$$ See Lemma 1 of [Panchenko, 2003].

I'm wondering if something similar holds assuming that $\mathbb{E} \exp(aX) ≤ \mathbb{E} \exp(aY)\; \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$. If we have an ineq. on MGFs, what can be said about the tails?

[Panchenko, 2003] Dmitry Panchenko, Symmetrization approach to concentration inequalities for empirical processes, *Annals of Probability*, 2003.